# Code coverage using istanbul(nyc) in mocha for GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, mocha.js, istanbul, nyc

I have surfed through internet but still I haven't got any solution. Can we do code coverage using nyc package in istanbul for graphQL API's. It is working fine and returning test results for rest API's. But I'm using the same mocha and istanbul(nyc) library for code coverage but it is not returning any test results for graphQL API's.

Comment: Still waiting for answers can anyone give any clarification. In case if have to edit this question reply me. Thanks